# Returning a false statement in function

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I have a function that is supposed to validate whether a relation is a function.

This is my function:

```
def isFunction(A,B,f):
    ky = [i for i,j in f] ##fetching the first element of f and placing it in ky
    for i in A:
        if ky.count(i) != 1: ##checks whether the all elements of A have a unique image in B
            return False
    for i in f:
        if i not in A:
            return False
    return True
```

These are the taken inputs:

```
A = [1, 2, 3,]   ##change inputs according to the needs
B= [4,5]
f=[[1,4],[2,5],[3 ,4], [7, 4]]
print (isFunction(A,B,f))
```

I should be getting a `False`, which is correct but if I do another test case:

```
A = [1, 2, 3,]
B = [4, 5]
f = [[1,4], [2,5], [3,4]]
print('Returns: ', isFunction(A, B, f))
```

I also get a `false` statement now, but I should get a `True` statement instead.
What is the error, and what do I do to change my function?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: The comment says that it's checking whether there's a unique image in B, but that code never uses `B`.

Comment: The second `for` loop will always return `False`. `i` is a list, `A` contains integers, so `i not in A` will always be true.

Comment: What are the `A` and `B` parameters for?

Comment: I think you mean more than just a function. Do you mean to check for an injective function? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)

Comment: I suspect that replacing `for i in A` with `for i,_ in A` will make your function do what you want it to do.

Comment: @Felix Checking for injectivity would mean checking that each j corresponds to a unique i among the pairs i,j in f. There is no evidence in the post that this is what OP wants.

Comment: @Ben that is literally his comment actually.

Comment: @Felix His comment is "all elements of A have a unique image in B". Injectivity would mean that f is a function and that "all elements of **B** (that are present in some pair (i,j) of f) correspond to a unique element of **A**"

Comment: @BenGrossmann `for i, _ in A` won't work. `A` is a list of integers, not pairs.

Comment: @Barmar That's a typo; I meant replacing `for i in f` with `for i,_ in f`.

Comment: @Ben perhaps he want surjective or bijective, either way, it’s not for us to guess what he wants, hence my ref to wikipedia so he (she?) can state the assignment clearly.

Comment: @Felix Again, there is no reason for us to believe that what they want is anything other than what has been explicitly stated, since nothing about the function or its comments points to injectivity or surjectivity.

Comment: @Ben except that.. all his examples are perfect functions, they map one domain to another.

Comment: in the first example, you see that the set in A is composed of 3 elements, and the set in B of 2 elements. In `f`, describes the function set (the elements of A mapping to B), but as you can see, there is an element 7 in `f` which is not part of the domain A. It should return False, which it is doing. However, when I do the other example, I should get a return `true` statement but I get a `false` instead. My question is what can I do to receive both correct statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following modifications to your program result in what I suspect is the desired behavior

Option 1 iterate through `ky` instead of `f` in the second for loop:

```
def isFunction(A,B,f):
    ky = [i for i,j in f] ##fetching the first element of f and placing it in ky
    for i in A:
        if ky.count(i) != 1: ##checks whether the all elements of A have a unique image in B
            return False
    for i in ky:
        if i not in A:
            return False
    return True
```

Here's an alternative approach

Option 2: take i to be the first element from each pair of f rather than the entire pair.

```
def isFunction(A,B,f):
    ky = [i for i,j in f] ##fetching the first element of f and placing it in ky
    for i in A:
        if ky.count(i) != 1: ##checks whether the all elements of A have a unique image in B
            return False
    for i,_ in f:
        if i not in A:
            return False
    return True
```

Technically, both of these are flawed approaches in that they allow for functions whose domain consists only of a subset of A. For example, we get an incorrect "true" for the case of

```
A = [1,2]
B = [1,2]
f = [(1,1)]
```

Also, you seem to assume that pairs within f are distinct, i.e. each pair `(i,j)` can appear at most once in the "function" `f`.

Here's the approach that I would take. This assumes that the domain must consist of the entire set A and that pairs within f are distinct.

```
def isFunction(A,B,f):
    inputs = [i for i,_ in f]
    in_set = set(inputs)
    return in_set == set(A) and\
           len(in_set) == len(inputs)
```

The condition `in_set == set(A)` returns True iff the set of inputs is equal to the entirety of the domain A, and the condition `len(in_set) == len(inputs)` returns True iff each input i appears only once with a pair (i,j) from f.

---

Edit in response to comment:

```
def isFunction(A,B,f):
    inputs, outputs = zip(*f)
    in_set = set(inputs)
    return in_set == set(A) and\
           len(in_set) == len(inputs) and\
           set(outputs) <= set(B)
```

Comment: okay, I get it now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @i_amgeek112 Glad that makes sense. In case you missed it, I added to my explanation with my most recent edit.

Comment: if I were to add the same conditions for target B, how would I go into adding it to the function?

Comment: @i_amgeek Could you clarify what exactly you mean by "the same conditions for target B"?

Comment: For example, if there's an element that is present in the set `f`, but not in set `B`, it would return false. How would I go into implementing that condition into the `isFunction` ?

Comment: @i_amgeek112 I understand now. See my latest edit